# React can't find the root component node for data-reactid value `.3r0ietj75s.0.0.0.0.0.1` during Server Side Rendering in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, server, rendering

I am trying to build an isomorphic React application using NodeJs.

The node server.js file uses 'node-jsx-babel', to transpile the Jsx files of my react component.

on server.js i got

```
require('node-jsx-babel').install({ extension: '.jsx'});
```

on my server route file, I call the react component like so.

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOMServer = require('react-dom/server');
var Catalog = React.createFactory(require('./js/src/Components/Catalog/Catalog'));

app.get('/routename', function(req, res){


var reactHtml = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(Catalog({
    columns: 3,
    ...

    }));
    // Output html rendered by react

    res.render('reactSearch.ejs', {reactOutput: reactHtml});
    });
```

The Catalog component upon mounting makes an api call to another node api, and obtains some data, which is successfully obtained in it's state variable this.state.data. The render block of this component looks like this.

```
render: function() {

var MenuList = this.state.data.menu.map(function(menuItem,index){

     return(
       <li key={index}>
           <a className="search_prevent" href={menuItem.u}> {menuItem.n} </a>

       </li>
     )
   });

return (
<ul className="menu">
   {MenuList}
</ul>

)
}
```

Upon reloading the browser at `localhost:<port>/routename`, The Node Application crashes with this error.

```
Warning: React can't find the root component node for data-reactid value `.3r0ietj75s.0.0.0.0.0.1`. If you're seeing this message, it probably means that you've loaded two copies of React on the page. At this time, only a single copy of React can be loaded at a time.
/Users/nikil/Documents/ReactIsomorphicDemo/node_modules/react/lib/ReactMount.js:715
    firstChildren[0] = deepestAncestor.firstChild;
```

**I can get the page to load fine without any errors if I remove the {MenuList} from inside the `<ul>` of the render block. If i replace {MenuList} with say Hello, the page renders with the ul and the word hello.
The application crashes when I try mapping through the data I obtained and assign it to the ul.**

I have ensured that the react component is not a sub dependency of any of my other components including React-DOM.

Below is an output of **npm ls** to show my dependency graph.

```html
─┬ algoliasearch@3.13.0
│ ├── agentkeepalive@2.0.3
│ ├─┬ debug@2.2.0
│ │ └── ms@0.7.1
│ ├─┬ debug-ms-fix-yui-compressor@2.2.2-future-reserved-word-fix-ms
│ │ └── algolia-ms@0.7.1-fix-future-reserved-words
│ ├─┬ envify@3.4.0
│ │ ├─┬ jstransform@10.1.0
│ │ │ ├── base62@0.1.1
│ │ │ ├── esprima-fb@13001.1001.0-dev-harmony-fb
│ │ │ └─┬ source-map@0.1.31
│ │ │   └── amdefine@1.0.0
│ │ └── through@2.3.8
│ ├── es6-promise@3.1.2
│ ├── events@1.1.0
│ ├── inherits@2.0.1
│ ├── load-script@1.0.0
│ ├── lodash@3.10.1
│ ├── lodash-compat@3.10.2
│ ├── querystring@0.2.0
│ ├── semver@5.1.0
│ └── tunnel-agent@0.4.2
├── ejs@2.4.1
├─┬ express@3.1.0
│ ├── buffer-crc32@0.1.1
│ ├── commander@0.6.1
│ ├─┬ connect@2.7.2
│ │ ├── bytes@0.1.0
│ │ ├── formidable@1.0.11
│ │ ├── pause@0.0.1
│ │ └── qs@0.5.1
│ ├── cookie@0.0.5
│ ├── cookie-signature@0.0.1
│ ├─┬ debug@2.2.0
│ │ └── ms@0.7.1
│ ├── fresh@0.1.0
│ ├── methods@0.0.1
│ ├── mkdirp@0.3.3
│ ├── range-parser@0.0.4
│ └─┬ send@0.1.0
│   └── mime@1.2.6
├── mime@1.2.11
├─┬ node-jsx-babel@0.14.2
│ ├─┬ babel-core@6.6.4
│ │ ├─┬ babel-code-frame@6.6.0
│ │ │ ├─┬ chalk@1.1.1
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ ansi-styles@2.2.0
│ │ │ │ │ └── color-convert@1.0.0
│ │ │ │ ├── escape-string-regexp@1.0.5
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ has-ansi@2.0.0
│ │ │ │ │ └── ansi-regex@2.0.0
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ strip-ansi@3.0.1
│ │ │ │ │ └── ansi-regex@2.0.0
│ │ │ │ └── supports-color@2.0.0
│ │ │ ├── esutils@2.0.2
│ │ │ ├── js-tokens@1.0.2
│ │ │ ├─┬ line-numbers@0.2.0
│ │ │ │ └── left-pad@0.0.3
│ │ │ └─┬ repeating@1.1.3
│ │ │   └─┬ is-finite@1.0.1
│ │ │     └── number-is-nan@1.0.0
│ │ ├─┬ babel-generator@6.6.4
│ │ │ ├─┬ detect-indent@3.0.1
│ │ │ │ ├── get-stdin@4.0.1
│ │ │ │ └── minimist@1.2.0
│ │ │ ├─┬ is-integer@1.0.6
│ │ │ │ └─┬ is-finite@1.0.1
│ │ │ │   └── number-is-nan@1.0.0
│ │ │ ├─┬ repeating@1.1.3
│ │ │ │ └─┬ is-finite@1.0.1
│ │ │ │   └── number-is-nan@1.0.0
│ │ │ └── trim-right@1.0.1
│ │ ├── babel-helpers@6.6.0
│ │ ├── babel-messages@6.6.0
│ │ ├─┬ babel-register@6.6.0
│ │ │ ├── core-js@2.1.3
│ │ │ ├─┬ home-or-tmp@1.0.0
│ │ │ │ ├── os-tmpdir@1.0.1
│ │ │ │ └── user-home@1.1.1
│ │ │ ├─┬ mkdirp@0.5.1
│ │ │ │ └── minimist@0.0.8
│ │ │ └─┬ source-map-support@0.2.10
│ │ │   └─┬ source-map@0.1.32
│ │ │     └── amdefine@1.0.0
│ │ ├─┬ babel-runtime@5.8.35
│ │ │ └── core-js@1.2.6
│ │ ├── babel-template@6.6.4
│ │ ├─┬ babel-traverse@6.6.4
│ │ │ ├── globals@8.18.0
│ │ │ ├─┬ invariant@2.2.0
│ │ │ │ └─┬ loose-envify@1.1.0
│ │ │ │   └── js-tokens@1.0.2
│ │ │ └─┬ repeating@1.1.3
│ │ │   └─┬ is-finite@1.0.1
│ │ │     └── number-is-nan@1.0.0
│ │ ├─┬ babel-types@6.6.4
│ │ │ ├── esutils@2.0.2
│ │ │ └── to-fast-properties@1.0.1
│ │ ├── babylon@6.6.4
│ │ ├── convert-source-map@1.2.0
│ │ ├─┬ debug@2.2.0
│ │ │ └── ms@0.7.1
│ │ ├── json5@0.4.0
│ │ ├── lodash@3.10.1
│ │ ├─┬ minimatch@2.0.10
│ │ │ └─┬ brace-expansion@1.1.3
│ │ │   ├── balanced-match@0.3.0
│ │ │   └── concat-map@0.0.1
│ │ ├── path-exists@1.0.0
│ │ ├── path-is-absolute@1.0.0
│ │ ├── private@0.1.6
│ │ ├── shebang-regex@1.0.0
│ │ ├── slash@1.0.0
│ │ └── source-map@0.5.3
│ └─┬ babel-preset-react@6.5.0
│   ├─┬ babel-plugin-syntax-flow@6.5.0
│   │ └─┬ babel-runtime@5.8.35
│   │   └── core-js@1.2.6
│   ├─┬ babel-plugin-syntax-jsx@6.5.0
│   │ └─┬ babel-runtime@5.8.35
│   │   └── core-js@1.2.6
│   ├─┬ babel-plugin-transform-flow-strip-types@6.6.4
│   │ └─┬ babel-runtime@5.8.35
│   │   └── core-js@1.2.6
│   ├─┬ babel-plugin-transform-react-display-name@6.5.0
│   │ └─┬ babel-runtime@5.8.35
│   │   └── core-js@1.2.6
│   ├─┬ babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx@6.6.4
│   │ ├─┬ babel-helper-builder-react-jsx@6.6.4
│   │ │ ├─┬ babel-types@6.6.4
│   │ │ │ ├─┬ babel-traverse@6.6.4
│   │ │ │ │ ├─┬ babel-code-frame@6.6.0
│   │ │ │ │ │ ├─┬ chalk@1.1.1
│   │ │ │ │ │ │ ├─┬ ansi-styles@2.2.0
│   │ │ │ │ │ │ │ └── color-convert@1.0.0
│   │ │ │ │ │ │ ├── escape-string-regexp@1.0.5
│   │ │ │ │ │ │ ├─┬ has-ansi@2.0.0
│   │ │ │ │ │ │ │ └── ansi-regex@2.0.0
│   │ │ │ │ │ │ ├─┬ strip-ansi@3.0.1
│   │ │ │ │ │ │ │ └── ansi-regex@2.0.0
│   │ │ │ │ │ │ └── supports-color@2.0.0
│   │ │ │ │ │ ├── js-tokens@1.0.2
│   │ │ │ │ │ └─┬ line-numbers@0.2.0
│   │ │ │ │ │   └── left-pad@0.0.3
│   │ │ │ │ ├── babel-messages@6.6.0
│   │ │ │ │ ├── babylon@6.6.4
│   │ │ │ │ ├─┬ debug@2.2.0
│   │ │ │ │ │ └── ms@0.7.1
│   │ │ │ │ ├── globals@8.18.0
│   │ │ │ │ ├─┬ invariant@2.2.0
│   │ │ │ │ │ └─┬ loose-envify@1.1.0
│   │ │ │ │ │   └── js-tokens@1.0.2
│   │ │ │ │ └─┬ repeating@1.1.3
│   │ │ │ │   └─┬ is-finite@1.0.1
│   │ │ │ │     └── number-is-nan@1.0.0
│   │ │ │ └── to-fast-properties@1.0.1
│   │ │ ├── esutils@2.0.2
│   │ │ └── lodash@3.10.1
│   │ └─┬ babel-runtime@5.8.35
│   │   └── core-js@1.2.6
│   └─┬ babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx-source@6.5.0
│     └─┬ babel-runtime@5.8.35
│       └── core-js@1.2.6
├─┬ react@0.14.7
│ ├─┬ envify@3.4.0
│ │ ├─┬ jstransform@10.1.0
│ │ │ ├── base62@0.1.1
│ │ │ ├── esprima-fb@13001.1001.0-dev-harmony-fb
│ │ │ └─┬ source-map@0.1.31
│ │ │   └── amdefine@1.0.0
│ │ └── through@2.3.8
│ └─┬ fbjs@0.6.1
│   ├── core-js@1.2.6
│   ├─┬ loose-envify@1.1.0
│   │ └── js-tokens@1.0.2
│   ├─┬ promise@7.1.1
│   │ └── asap@2.0.3
│   ├── ua-parser-js@0.7.10
│   └── whatwg-fetch@0.9.0
├── react-addons-css-transition-group@0.14.7
├── react-dom@0.14.7
├── react-pager@1.1.2
└─┬ rest-js@1.1.2
  ├── es6-promise@2.3.0
  └─┬ superagent@0.21.0
    ├── component-emitter@1.1.2
    ├── cookiejar@2.0.1
    ├─┬ debug@2.2.0
    │ └── ms@0.7.1
    ├── extend@1.2.1
    ├─┬ form-data@0.1.3
    │ ├── async@0.9.2
    │ └─┬ combined-stream@0.0.7
    │   └── delayed-stream@0.0.5
    ├── formidable@1.0.14
    ├── methods@1.0.1
    ├── qs@1.2.0
    ├─┬ readable-stream@1.0.27-1
    │ ├── core-util-is@1.0.2
    │ ├── inherits@2.0.1
    │ ├── isarray@0.0.1
    │ └── string_decoder@0.10.31
    └── reduce-component@1.0.1
```

Not sure what is causing this problem. Would appreciate any thoughts that can help solve this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem was the Async nature of the API.
Upon inlining the data within the file, everything rendered fine.

Just need to put in some kind of callback mechanism to make this work.

Weird error message though.